# Pandas - locating using index vs column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't understand why the codes below produces 2 different outputs when both referring to a column in a csv file. The second also includes rows that have NaN values, whereas the first code removes it. I don't know why it does that though so can someone please explain? Thanks!

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('climate_data_2017.csv')
is_over_35 = df["Maximum temperature (C)"] > 35
```

vs

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('climate_data_2017.csv')
is_over_35 = df[[3]] > 35
```

Comment: `df['col']` is a Series. `df[['col']]` is a DataFrame. You can't be referring to the same column with `df["Maximum temperature (C)"]` and `df[[3]]`. You can't just use positional indexer without a method. Can you make this question fully reproducible with a sample DataFrame?

Comment: @HenryEcker, I'm not sure I follow you. Is there a way to make the series using the index then? Since I prefer to use index over the whole column name.

Comment: If you want to access by index location  you need to use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) `df.iloc[:, 3]` for example. Default getitem will always be label based lookup.